# Laravel 5 Model Accessor Methods not working

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5, accessor

I am attempting to write some accessor methods according to my best interpretation of the documentation and they do not seem to be working. I am attempting to decrypt an attribute that I am encrypting when it comes into the database via an API call that fires in a scheduled artisan console command. I have a Model that looks like this:

```
 <?php namespace App;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use ET_Client;
use ET_DataExtension;
use ET_DataExtension_Row;
use Crypt;

//child implementation
class MasterPreference extends Model {

////these fields can be mass assigned
    protected $fillable = [
        //
        'SMS_OPT_IN',
        'EMAIL_OPT_IN',
        'CUSTOMER_NAME',
        'CUSTOMER_ID'
    ];

    protected $DE_Names = ['MasterPreferences', 'SubPreferences'];

    protected $results = '';


    //instantiate and replicate
    function __construct()
    {

    }


    /**
     * 
     *
     * @return $getResult
     */
    public function getData()
    {

    }


    /**
     * store to the Db
     */
    public function store($results)
    {

    }


    /**
     * decrypt CUSTOMER_ID
     * @param $value
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getCustomerIdAttribute($value)
    {

        return Crypt::decrypt($value);
    }

    public function getAccountHolderAttribute($value)
    {
        return $value . 'testing';
    }

    /**
     * ecnrypt Customer ID
     *
     * @param $value
     */
    public function setCustomerIdAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['CUSTOMER_ID'] = Crypt::encrypt($value);
    }



}
```

As you can see above I've created 2 accessor methods one for an attribute named CUSTOMER_ID, and another for an attrib named ACCOUNT_HOLDER. When I store like $all = MasterPreference::all() and dd($all) in my index method in the MasterPreferencesController, these attributes are unchanged. Is there another step to calling these accessor methods? Shouldn't they just work by the magic of Laravel?

I appreciate any help! I'm fairly stumped and cannot find this in the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that Laravel assumes your field names are lower case. If your field name was for example `custome_id` it would correctly change the value of it.

You could also try the following:

```
public function getCustomerIdAttribute($)
{
    return Crypt::decrypt($this->attributes['CUSTOMER_ID']);
}
```

or

```
public function getCustomerIdAttribute($)
{
    return Crypt::decrypt($this->CUSTOMER_ID);
}
```

then access that value with

```
MasterPreference::find($id)->customer_id
```

not sure if and which will work.

Comment: Which one is correct? Why is this marked as the correct answer?

Answer (score 2):

Let's see where the magic went wrong.

**The Basics:**

1) You are extending the class `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`. Functions that you declare in `MasterPreference` class, will override the parent class's function, where the names match.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.extends.php

**The Problem:**

`MasterPreference` class has an empty `__construct` function.

This overrides the `__construct()` function of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` which is:

```
/**
 * Create a new Eloquent model instance.
 *
 * @param  array  $attributes
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct(array $attributes = array())
{
    $this->bootIfNotBooted();

    $this->syncOriginal();

    $this->fill($attributes);
}
```

Your magic of Accessors & Mutators happens in this vortex of code.

**The Solution:**

Hence, `MasterPreference`'s `__construct` should be as follows:

```
public function __construct(array $attributes = array())
{
     parent::__construct($attributes);
}
```

Comment: You guys are both right to some extent. I realized last night that the magic does happen if you assign the attribute directly rather than pulling everything out of the model. Like: `//look them up
            $all = MasterPreference::all();

            $idArray = array();

            //values get decrypted by accessor
            foreach($all as $k => $val) {
                $idArray[] = $val->customer_id;
            }`           BUT also the blank constructor was an issue.

Comment: Yeah, they are called `accessors` on purpose. You have to access them for the magic to happen. Even if you call, `toArray()` or `toJson()`, the accessor functions will get applied.

Comment: Thank you! You guys were both very helpful!